# Is there an alternative to body or container tags in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm very new to website designing and have learned a bit of HTML and CSS.

I was following this website designing tutorial and halfway through it came across this tutorial on creating a CSS RESPONSIVE CARD HOVER EFFECT for the second section of my webpage.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8b2mTq0Xrtw&ab_channel=OnlineTutorials

The problem I faced here is getting my images aligned at the body, and container tags because I already have them in my style sheet and when I make the changes he recommended, it messes up the alignment of my entire web design.

Are there alternatives tags I could use to work around this? I have tried using div class and setting a different name but it just doesn't work!

I know it's a fairly easy fix, but I've tried many things, even creating a second style sheet but it still doesn't seem to work!

Comment: instead of video, can you please just share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need the body styling that he put on the tutorial, it is just there
   to center content on the screen so we can see it better.
2. If you have a .container class already in your code, you can always change the
   name of the class to card-container or new-container or
   whatever you think is suitable.

```css
.card-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 1100px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      padding: 30px;
    }
    
.card-container .card {
    /*
      Styling for card
    */
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I managed to solve my problem thanks to you